# How to store and query a unix 10-digit epoch time into something human readable in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, timestamp

I have a UNIX epoch time stored in a set of data I'm trying to import in the following format *without* milliseconds `1006,785,1502054277,8` (third entry). I noticed I can only store this in Cassandra as a timestamp. However, when I try to convert the time when querying it comes across as follows using this query:

```
select player_id, server_id, dateof(mintimeuuid(last_login)) as timestamp, sessions from servers_by_user where server_id = 440 and player_id = 217442

 player_id | server_id | timestamp                       | sessions
-----------+-----------+---------------------------------+---------------
    217442 |       440 | 1970-01-18 06:38:03.382000+0000 |              1
```

That's obviously not right because that epoch time is actually `2017-08-06T21:17:57+00:00`.

I tried to store the data as `timeuuid` but then I get this error presumably because it is not a 13-digit epoch time: `Failed to import 1 rows: ParseError - Failed to parse 1502054277 : badly formed hexadecimal UUID string,`.

What would be the best way to store a 10-digit UNIX epoch time and to query it back into something that is human-readable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you notice is that unix timestamps are seconds since epoch - but timestamps in cassandra are stored as milliseconds since epoch instead.

First row is what you actually stored, the second one is what you want:

```
cqlsh:demo> SELECT id, blobAsBigint(timestampAsBlob(ts)) FROM demo3;

 id                                   | system.blobasbigint(system.timestampasblob(ts))
--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------
 b7bac930-7b3e-11e7-a5b3-73178ecf2b4e |                                      1502054277
 bfb37f10-7b3e-11e7-a5b3-73178ecf2b4e |                                   1502054277000

(2 rows)
cqlsh:demo> SELECT id, dateof(mintimeuuid(blobAsBigint(timestampAsBlob(ts)))) FROM demo3;

 id                                   | system.dateof(system.mintimeuuid(system.blobasbigint(system.timestampasblob(ts))))
--------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 b7bac930-7b3e-11e7-a5b3-73178ecf2b4e |                                                           1970-01-18 09:14:14+0000
 bfb37f10-7b3e-11e7-a5b3-73178ecf2b4e |                                                           2017-08-06 21:17:57+0000

(2 rows)
cqlsh:demo>
```

(using something like `timestampasblob()` in regular code is not a good idea, just as demo here to see whats going on under the hood)

If you can - do not store unix timestamps in cassandra but use timestamps if you want the 'magic'. Of course you can deal with conversion from seconds to timestamp in your code - using timestamps directly is much more convienent.

While you note you are importing some data, simply multiply them with 1000 before importing and you are done.

I can't try on my cluster right now, but with cassandra 3.x you can have user defined functions (UDF) to do conversions, but they need to be enabled in your cluster in cassandra.yaml in java or javascript (others as python are possible). See https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/latest/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDF.html.

```
CREATE FUNCTION IF NOT EXISTS toMilliseconds(input int) 
   CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
   RETURNS int
   LANGUAGE java AS '
     return int*1000;
   ';
```

Or just convert directly to timestamp. Some blog post from Datastax with more examples: https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/user-defined-functions-in-cassandra-3-0